# Variation of the classical infamous looping dilemma

Tags: javascript, closures

Just about everyone has ran into this specific issue:

```
function addLinks () {
    for (var i=0, link; i<5; i++) {
        link = document.createElement("a");
        link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;
        link.onclick = function () {
            alert(i);
        };
        document.body.appendChild(link);
    }
}
window.onload = addLinks;
```

The value of `i` after the loop is cached. A closure can be used to create a "live" reference:

```
function addLinks () {
    for (var i=0, link; i<5; i++) {
        link = document.createElement("a");
        link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;
        link.onclick = function (num) {
            return function () {
                alert(num);
            };
        }(i);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
    }
}
window.onload = addLinks;
```

We can also use self executing anon fns to create closures as well, etc..

**My situation**

The issue I'm facing is the same, but the context is a little different. Here's a [failing example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/r7Ekj/2/show/):

Hit 'add more lis' a few times and click 'hit me', which will alert `-1`. The value of `maxIndex` is cached. Relevant code:

```
  var attached = false;

function actions() {
    var elements = $('body').find('li');
    var maxIndex = elements.length -1;


        var cycle = {
            next: function() {
                alert( maxIndex );
            }
        };

        if ( !attached ) {
            $('#next').click(function(e) {
                cycle.next();
            });
            attached = true;
        }

};

actions();

$('#add').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('<li/>').text('god').appendTo('body');
    actions();
});
```

I've tried applying closures to no avail. ( see http://jsfiddle.net/Bfcus/23/ and down to /1/ ).

I don't want to use `with` statements or `let` statements/expressions to solve this. I know another way this is solvable is by changing `maxIndex` to be a property of a named object. Here's a working [example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/r7Ekj/1/show/) doing it that way.

What I'm wondering is - is there a way of having it work while keeping the `elements` variable definition inside of the `action` function, and having the `maxIndex` variable defined in the same scope? Basically, can http://fiddle.jshell.net/r7Ekj/2/show/ be adjusted to work almost in the same manner as it is, without relying on with/let/object property?

Comment: You mention that values are 'cached' -- more accurately, a closure is really just holding a reference to the scope chain that ultimately references the original instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird, sometimes creating a thorough question actually helps you solve it and I swear I didn't have it solved beforehand...

I just created the `maxIndex` variable outside of the `actions` scope and actually assign it inside.. this makes it work because it isn't defined in the same function scope and so the binding behaves differently.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/r7Ekj/9/

( How embarassing? )